# Why can't I reach the LAN side of a slave vrrp router?

Tags: linux, routing, router, linux-networking

I have a dual linux firewall/router setup that is connected to 2 different upstream providers.  Internally the default route is a failover using vrrp.

The setup looks something like this.  The routes are provided to the routers via BGP.

```
Provider A (x.x.x.57) - Router 1 [WAN](x.x.x.58) [LAN](a.a.a.130/128)
                                                   +----- VRRP (a.a.a.129/128) [default gw]
Provider B (y.y.y.61) - Router 2 [WAN](y.y.y.62) [LAN](a.a.a.131/128)
```

It all works correctly in general.

However, what I've noticed is that when Router 1 is the master for the VRRP, a.a.a.131 is not able to be pinged from a client that routes through Provider A.  Likewise, if Router 2 is the master we cannot ping a.a.a.130. I also cannot ssh to that address.  I can however ssh or ping the WAN side of both routers at any time.  Since I can reach the WAN interface of Router 2 when Router 1 is the master, and forwarding is turned on, how come I can't directly reach the LAN side of the same router when it's not the master ?

What would be the cause of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.  I found the following link about reverse path filtering to be very helpful.  In following it's suggestions I managed to fix the problem I was having.

[Disabling reverse path filtering in complex networks](http://www.tolaris.com/2009/07/13/disabling-reverse-path-filtering-in-complex-networks/)